# SSIS FTP - Download large data files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement at work where we have to move large csv/Excel data files from vendor FTP Server to our local server. I have been researching on this and thinking to use SSIS FTP Task for this requirement. Can SSIS FTP Task handle large data files? How much large data can be supported with SSIS FTP Task.

Large file size transferring recommendations that you can think of.

Any suggestion in this regards would be appreciated. This will help us in deciding the right way of achieving this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

We are analyzing which route to go SSIS or any other tool that can help us in achieving the task

Comment: I see nothing in the Microsoft Learn docs that says anything about large file sizes, so I would assume there is no hard limitation on the size. I would try it and see how it works, but the FTP task would be the way to go. If it needs to be SFTP, I believe a different approach it needed, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Define "large."

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Appreciate it.